# ¿Cómo loguearte con Apache contra un servidor de dominio LDAP mediante un atributo multivalor?

Tags: apache

Estoy haciendo que en mi empresa, el servidor Apache autentique a los usuarios haciendo uso del servidor de dominio `LDAP` que tenemos.

En principio, pensaba utilizar el atributo de la cuenta de correo electrónico (mail) como login, que en el archivo de configuración de Apache quedaría así:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication system: please insert e-mail and password"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
LDAPReferrals default
AuthLDAPURL ldap://host:port/basedn?mail?sub?(objectClass=user)
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=usrbind,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=es"
AuthLDAPBindPassword usrbindpassword
Require valid-user
```

De este modo, Apache es capaz de autenticar correctamente a los usuarios.

El asunto es que en esta empresa cada trabajador tiene varias cuentas de correo electrónico (unos más y otros menos, casi todas diferenciadas por el dominio), y ahora se quiere que el usuario pueda loguearse con uno cualquiera de esos correos, no sólo con el principal que está en el atributo `mail`.

En el servidor `LDAP`, tenemos un atributo llamado `proxyAddresses` que contiene todos los correos electrónicos asociados a cada usuario. Es un atributo multivalor (cada correo es un valor). Si cambio en el archivo de configuración la `URL LDAP` por ésta:

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://host:port/basedn?proxyAddresses?sub?(objectClass=user)
```

Ya no puedo loguearme. No encuentra el usuario.

¿A qué se debe? ¿No se puede autenticar un usuario contra `LDAP` haciendo uso de un atributo multivalor, aunque éste sea único (nadie más tiene ninguno de mis varios correos)? Y si se puede, ¿cómo se hace? ¿En qué estoy fallando?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no es exactamente lo que buscas, pero quizá te pueda servir de ayuda
[Autenticación en Apache con Windows Active Directory](http://desdelaconsola.es/autenticacion-en-apache-con-windows-active-directory/)